# D3.js wrong column order in csv file

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I'm trying to import a csv that has the following column order:

```
country,2004,2008,2012
eu 28 none,,11.1,12.8
eu 28 one language,,35.7,36.6
eu 28 two languages,,53.1,50.6
eu 27 none,8.3,11.2,12.9
eu 27 one language,54.7,35.9,36.7
eu 27 two languages,,52.9,50.3
```

after doing

```
 d3.keys(csv[0])
```

somehow the columns are imported as:

```
 ["2004", "2008", "2012", "country"]
```

Why is this happening? I'm using the column order as discriminator for what symbol should be shown so it's quite a big problem for me.

Some of the code used

```
d3.csv( folder + "/" + file, function(csv) { 
    var allheaders = d3.keys(csv[0]);
    console.log(d3.keys(csv[0]));
```

Comment: can you show us some of the code that you use to import the csv?

Comment: added it above in the text

Comment: The order of the keys is undefined, this couldn't be clearer in the [API docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_keys) .  The point is though that it doesn't matter because you can get what you want using `csv[i][column_name]` or `csv[i].column_name`.

Comment: Thank you for the link. What you suggest would be great if I have the column name. This will be used to create  several different barcharts from several hundred different csvs with several different column names, so it is quite the problem. Up to now I always assumed (because it always happened ) that it was importing the columns in the order written in the csv or tsv I was feeding in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bring it in as a text file, then you can exploit the fact that `d3.cvs.parseRows()` returns an array.  This means that the order will be as per the original text.

The fundamental problem with your code is that `d3.csv` returns an array of *objects*, the ordering of the members of an object is not defined, this is a javaScript thing...

### [#Working Code](http://bl.ocks.org/cool-Blue/0a6ac52bb2e3f9feeaaa)

[image: pic]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    div {
      white-space: pre;
    }
    td, th {
      outline: 1px solid white;
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
    th {
      text-align: left;
    }
    td:not(:first-child) {
      text-align: right;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="d3 CB.js"></script>-->
<script>
  d3.text("data.csv", function (text) {
    var csv = d3.csv.parse(text), allheaders = d3.csv.parseRows(text)[0],
      table = d3.select("body").append("table");
    table.append("thead")
      .append("tr").selectAll("th")
      .data(allheaders).enter()
        .append("th")
        .text(function(d){return d});
    table.append("tbody").datum(csv)
        .selectAll("tr")
        .data(function(d){
          return d
        })
          .enter().append("tr")
            .selectAll("td")
            .data(function(row){
              return allheaders.map(function(h) { return row[h]})
            }).enter().append("td")
            .text(function(d) {
              return d
            });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```